# Evento de campo Due Date react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formularios, react-hooks, next.js

Tengo un input due date , pero lo que tengo pensado es agregar por default el / en el campo cuando este se este digitando por ejemplo 02(/ "Esta barra se agrego en el input automaticamente")25, tengo la idea de controlarlo por onKeydown pero no me ha ido muy bien no se si tengan referencias de como hicieron algo parecido se los agradeceria [image: Esto era lo que estaba haciendo pero bueno no hice mucho :,v]

Comment: Yo te aconsejaría alguna librería que ya te haga eso antes de romperte un monton de tiempo la cabeza. Puedes usar [https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-mask]

Comment: [Aqui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-mask) el enlace que dejó @Suso

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.